# Apache 2.4 preserve client IP to Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat8, apache2.4

Our current setup is Win 2008 R2 Std server, Apache 2.2.22 http, Tomcat 8.0

We are using Apache for reverse proxy and the client IP address is passed from Apache to Tomcat using the following code in the Tomcat server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" internalProxies="127\.0\.0\.1" />
```

When we upgrade to Apache 2.4.25 we no longer get the client IP address passed, all we see is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1.

It seems like we have tried everything that Google has to offer including setting X-Forwarded-For (in both Apache & Tomcat), changing the Apache config to include mod_remoteip and setting the LogFormat to use %a instead of %h.

Can anyone advise of other options to try or a way to troubleshoot where the client IP is being lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the upgrade enabled IPv6 and you'd have to add the IPv6 loopback address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` to `internalProxies` e.g. `"127\.0\.0\.1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"`

<sub>*Edit by another user: changed "126" to "127" otherwise the answer won't work. Because Stackoverflow requires "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?", I'm forced to append this edit reason text.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Hanz, we thought we had dealt with IPv6 in Apache but didn't realise it was still flowing through to Tomcat, putting the 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 in the Valve expression fixed it.